# Creating subset of large JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm not too familiar with Python and I have a large JSON file that I first want to pre-process before doing anything with it.

I have a -not proper- JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"name" : "Bob", "text" : "abc", "timestamp": "09 13, 2009"}

{"name" : "..", "text" : "..", "timestamp": ".."}


...


{"name" : "..", "text" : "..", "timestamp": ".."}
```

This file has over a million of these dictionary objects inside, I want to iterate over each dictionary and only keep the keys and corresponding values of `"name"`  and `"text"` for example and leaving `"timestamp"`  out.

How can I achieve this? The reason I want to do this is in an attempt to throw all the information out that I don't need to shrink the size of the data set.

Thanks!

edit:

Code that I'm trying to run now is the following

```
def load_json(filename):


alltext = []
i = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:


  for line in fd:
    textLine = json.loads( line )


    alltext.append( textLine )
    print i
    i = i + 1

return alltext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = load_json('file.json')
```

This however returns a memory error, it breaks around 1/3 of the file.

Comment: Is that really what the file looks like? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: It's better if you add to the post a REAL chunk of the file you are parsing..

Comment: @Rawing I added comma's between each key-value pair, is that what you mean?

Comment: @user888 That's only part of the problem. This file looks like a sequence of dicts, but that's not valid JSON. If anything, they'd have to be enclosed in a list.

Comment: @Rawing I see what you mean now, it is indeed not a valid JSON (i'm not familiar with JSON either so I assumed it was, as I was told so..)

Comment: If you just want to remove all keys other than `name` and `text`, `textLine= {'name': textLine['name'], 'text': textLine['text']}` should do. However, that probably won't reduce the memory footprint by much. You may have to rewrite your code so that it doesn't require loading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming the file is a valid json and you jist omitted the commas and braces in your question)

If you can use json.load(open(filename)) without getting an exception - that's probably the simplest option.
If you can't - you're best friend is ijson (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson) or another streaming json library that can read the json chunk by chunk.

Update:
After a second thought, you can also try to split the file with a good text editor to a few files that json.load can handle

Comment: Any thoughts on splitting the file? Notepad++ couldn't open it because it was too big (2GB).

Comment: Maybe atom.I found vim also very powerful

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a *nix environment? You can use the split command as below.

```
split --lines=30000 --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=5 file.json chunk
```

Then run the same code on each chunk. (iterating over the chunks may cause the same memory errors though. Try it out.)